# 504 Gateway Timeout error with HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
var client = new HttpClient(requestHandler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(hostUrl),
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Configuration.RequestTimeout*1000)
};
```

I have a client application that executes POST request to send some data to target. As you can see that Timeout value for client is being set explicitly. In the application it is set to 20 minutes because some time request can take longer to execute.
What I am observing is that this 20 minute timeout value is not being honored. If request takes longer that 5 minutes, it will always return 504 error at exact 5 minute mark.
This is a C# (.Net 4.5.1) library that executes these requests.
Is there some other setting that I am missing? Or there is some rogue PROXY that could be altering the behavior?

Thanks

Comment: In my brief search I couldn't find a 5 minute timeout, but if it is HttpClient related, you'd want to look the time outs in ServicePointManager a global object that affects HttpClient http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. At this point I am not sure if it is my client or the target server that could be doing it. Only thing I know is that target is nginx server. And it could be that it has a service time out of 5 minutes. I am checking on this from the customer.